# How to use well ngmin for annotate angularjs files and usemin to produce a dist file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I'm using a yeoman web app template that runs an AngularJS app.
`usemin` is great, but AngularJS files must be pre-processed with `ngmin` to be annotated before being uglified and minified by `usemin`.

I can produce a single, concatenated file of annotated AngularJS controllers, directives, services, etc. using `ngmin`.

```
 ngmin: {
     build: {
         src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/js/one.js','<%= yeoman.app %>/js/two.js'],
         dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/ng/annotated.js' 
     }
 }
```

Basically I run a build that successfully created `annotated.js`.

What I want is declare `annotated.js` file in `index.html` to inform `usemin` to use that file only for **distribution**, not the ones I mention for **development**.

```
  <!-- build:js js/app.min.js -->  //annotated.js only must be processed instead of those 2 files.
  <script src="js/one.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/two.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

For reference, my usemin config:

```
  useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css']
    }
```

For reference, my build task:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'ngmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you used `yo webapp` to generator an application that you then plugged Angular in to? For future Angular apps you create (or if it's not too late for this one), there's a generator for that! https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Here is a link and some code that shows how the `ngmin` task is pre-configured with the Angular generator:

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/v0.4.0/templates/common/Gruntfile.js#L326-335

```
ngmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
    }]
  }
}
```

Plug that in, tweak as necessary, and let me know if it works!

Comment: For some reason the annotated file processed by usemin sucks (it throws an exception). Ngmin produces a "no problem" single file. Therefore I use that file instead of a uglyfied file that fails (because I have lost enough time). Thanks for your help anyway :)